Where to put & operator in forward declaration of a class function in c++
I want to declare a class function for erasing a playlist.
In the playlist.h file:
class playlist {
    elem* head;
public:
    void init();
    void print();
    bool insert(char* newName, char* newArtist);
    bool remove(char* oldName, char* oldArtist);
    bool search(char* name, char* artist);
    void destroy();
};

In the playlist.cpp file:
void playlist::destroy() {
    elem* p=head,*q;
    while(p!=nullptr) {
        q=p;
        p=p->next;
        delete q;
    }
}

With this method however I think the function just modifies the function local copy of
head and not the actual variable.
I know that the & operator is used in function arguments for non-class functions for this problem, but I can't figure out where to put it.

void playlist::destroy() { while(head) delete std::exchange(head, head->next); }


With this method however I think the function just modifies the
function local copy of head and not the actual variable.

delete does not modify the variable. It does free the allocated memory. If you ant to modify head you need to use this member:
void playlist::destroy() 
{
    while(head != nullptr) 
    {
         elem* toDelete = head;
         head = head -> next;
         delete toDelete;
    }
}

You do not need to use &


With this method however I think the function just modifies the function local copy of head and not the actual variable.

It does, but the memory is released correctly.
It would be sufficient to set head=nullptr at the end of the existing method.

What you actually asked for is a reference to the pointer data member head, which you'd write as
elem *& p = head;

or, more simply,
auto& p = head;

but you don't really need this. You can either just work directly on the member head in the first place (as in the other answer), or update it once at the end (as above).

Final notes: your class should normally have a destructor (which could just call destroy, if you still need that method) and constructor (instead of init method).
In any real code you'd probably use a std::list or other container instead of mixing a singly-linked list into your class logic by hand, and any container should clean up its storage automatically.
Oh, and & isn't an operator in this context, it's just part of the type. You may be mixing it with the & operator which takes the address of something - that would have given you a pointer to pointer, and you don't need that either.
